# Mysql - Ignored state in where clause

Tags: mysql

I try to use this query to get all the user from selected gym.

My problem is that the query ignoring this part: `ual.user_id = weekUsers.user_id`

It seems like the query taking all the user ids that match the the dates I selected without checking if this users are in the gym I want to select.

In the image I put you can see that `ual.user_id`and `weekUsers.user_id` are not equal and still I got them in the results.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT count(ual.user_id), FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ual.time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ual.time) -1, 7)) as weekNum, 

        ual.user_id, weekUsers.user_id, u.id, u.gym

        FROM user_activity_log ual

        LEFT OUTER JOIN user u

        ON u.gym = 3

        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ualWeek.user_id FROM user_activity_log ualWeek 

        GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ualWeek.time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ualWeek.time) -1, 7)), ualWeek.user_id 

        HAVING count(ualWeek.user_id) > 1) weekUsers

        ON u.id = weekUsers.user_id

        WHERE 

        (ual.time BETWEEN '2014-02-09' AND '2015-02-09') OR (('2014-02-09' IS NULL) OR ('2015-02-09' IS NULL))

        AND ual.user_id = weekUsers.user_id

        GROUP BY ual.user_id
```

[image]

Comment: `a OR b AND c` interpreted as `a OR (b AND c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's interpret your `(ual.time BETWEEN '2014-02-09' AND '2015-02-09') OR (('2014-02-09' IS NULL) OR ('2015-02-09' IS NULL))` expression.

Denoting `(ual.time BETWEEN '2014-02-09' AND '2015-02-09')` as `A` and `(('2014-02-09' IS NULL) OR ('2015-02-09' IS NULL))` as `B` we get `A or B`.

So we have  `A or B AND ual.user_id = weekUsers.user_id`.

Due to default operation priority it will be interpreted like `A or (B AND ual.user_id = weekUsers.user_id)` so if `A` is true, then the whole logical expression is true and `ual.user_id = weekUsers.user_id` is not checked, simply ignored.

You can refer to http://www.bennadel.com/blog/126-sql-and-or-order-of-operations.htm
and http://www.bennadel.com/blog/126-sql-and-or-order-of-operations.htm
to more detail about operator precedence.